# How to list all the models that belong to another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreign-keys

I'm building a small system for a restaurant.

I'm currently stuck at listing efficiently all the models that belong to a `product_type` the types are: `food`, `beverages`, and `apparel_items`.

Each product Type has multiple kinds of products that belong to them for example `food` has many `wraps`, many `salads`, many `sandwiches`, etc.

The point of this is to have a button for each of the Product Types which when clicked, depending on the id of the type selected, lists all the models that belong to it as buttons so in turn you can click any of them and then list the database records for the model in question.

Example: Food, Beverages => click food => shows buttons for: wraps, salads and sandwiches => click wraps => Lists all the wraps

```
class ProductType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :apparel_items
  has_many :chapata_items
  has_many :combos
  has_many :croissants
  has_many :fruits
  has_many :green_challenges
  has_many :hot_drinks
  has_many :infusions
  has_many :juices
  has_many :molletes
  has_many :omelettes
  has_many :salads
  has_many :sandwiches
  has_many :shakes
  has_many :sincronizadas
  has_many :slices
  has_many :smooth_drinks
  has_many :super_drinks
  has_many :water_drinks
  has_many :wrap_items
end
```

How can I list all the models that belong to another one so that I can program this efficiently?

Would it be better to create a model for each of the Product Types (Food, Beverages, Apparel Items) and make only those three belong to the Product Type model?

Comment: You should include your models definitions in your question.

Comment: Added the model definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ActiveRecord::Reflection](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reflect_on_association) to inspect the associations for any model.

So `Food.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many)` returns an array of `ActiveRecord::Reflection::HasManyReflection` objects, with one for each food type that your `Food` model `has_many` of. Each of these reflections has a name, which is the name you set when you declare the `has_many` relationship.

You can then use the names of these reflections to build the list of products like so:

```
food_product_types = Food.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many).map(&:name)

# 'food_product_types' equals [:wraps, :salads, :sandwiches, etc...]
# Now, create buttons for each food product type
```

Of course, if your product types have associations that are not products, you will need to filter them out.

Comment: you can simplify this with `Food.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many).map(&:name)`

Comment: @jaydel Good call! I updated my answer to use your simplification.

Answer (score 1):

Your schema could certainly benefit from some denormalizing. There are many ways to approach the design, including suggested by you separation of models for product groups.

But, more importantly, you should consider why are you trying to put all the various products into separate models. Are they really that different from the standpoint of the workflow that uses them?

Maybe it worth it to just keep the truly shared set of fields in the `Product` model and put all the additional attributes into `Attribute` model? The `product_type` then will become just a field of `Product` and you will be able to do lots of wonderful stuff in a straightforward and performant manner.